# How to fetch the response body of all the requests loaded for a page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, phantomjs

I am currently working on a tool that requires fetching data from a webpage. (something similar to scraping but not exactly). What I need is a way to get the response body for all requests loaded for a page. I found a solution(confess.js) which uses phantomjs to fetch the body of the main (initiator) requests. List down the the URLs, headers and cookies for the main and sub requests, even the body size. But I can't seem to find a way to fetch the body data for the sub requests(resources like JS, CSS, Images etc and any xhr requests). What could be the best way to achieve this? (I do not want to hit each url individually thereby doubling the number of hits on my webpage) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i think you have to make a browser-extension. You have to get "i the middle" of the page and the source(s). See how  Chrome Dev does almost the same job (on the network tab). Alternative: Use Selenium or Cypress.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a simple answer:
https://mitmproxy.org/

install it locally and configure your browser to use this proxy .
than you can track all the traffic .(and will support https easily)

if you need a programmatic access to this data, you better take a look at some nodejs proxy libraries .(http://anyproxy.io, https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

you want a "reverse proxy" where you pass-through all requests.
then you get control over the request / response of all outgoing requests from the page.
you can "catch" urls, bodys , etc ..

Comment: Makes sense. I was worried about my page slowing down (I could be wrong about this) if passed through a proxy, but I realize there is no other way. I opted for chrome-remote-interface, which I personally found, gave me more control. Thanks